# Get data in sucess(Ajax) from URL in JavaScript angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I am using angular mobile Ui frame work. I am getting data from URL in controller. But right now i want to get particular data in success part. I will show my code snippet for hints.

HTML:

```
   <div class="jumbtron scrollable-content text-center bg-color">
   <div class="row">
          <div class="bgImage">  
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group img-responsive"  ng-controller="MyControllerCity"> 
              <div ng-repeat="prdct in cityProduct">
                   <a href="#/category-prduct" style="color:#763428; font-weight:bold;">
                      <img  src="{{prdct.categoryImage}}">
                    </a>
              </div>
          </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

HTML OUTPUT 
[image]

Controller:

```
.controller('MyControllerCity',function($scope, $http){ 
        $http({
                method:'get',
                url:'http://192.168.0.3/sf/app/city-home/1',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            }).success(function(data, status,headers, config) {
                $scope.cityProduct = data; 
                console.log("aaaaaaa" + cityProduct.categoryId);

            }).error(function(data, status, headers ,config) {

        })

})
```

> console.log("aaaaaaa" + cityProduct.categoryId);

But categoryId not show in console.

JSON Screen shot:
[image]

Here is the JSON response:

```
[{
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/cake.jpg",
    "categoryName": "cakes",
    "categoryId": 4
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/flowers.jpg",
    "categoryName": "flowers-and-bouquets",
    "categoryId": 12
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/chocolates.jpg",
    "categoryName": "chocolates-for-all",
    "categoryId": 63
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/mugs.jpg",
    "categoryName": "Mugs",
    "categoryId": 34
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/figurines.jpg",
    "categoryName": "figurines",
    "categoryId": 84
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/giftframes.jpg",
    "categoryName": "gift-and-photo-frames",
    "categoryId": 106
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/greetingcards.jpg",
    "categoryName": "greeting-cards",
    "categoryId": 103
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/handicrafts.jpg",
    "categoryName": "handicrafts",
    "categoryId": 44
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/penstands.jpg",
    "categoryName": "pen-stands",
    "categoryId": 142
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/combos.jpg",
    "categoryName": "gift-combos",
    "categoryId": 99
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/softtoys.jpg",
    "categoryName": "soft-toys",
    "categoryId": 104
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/diecasttoys.jpg",
    "categoryName": "diecast-toys",
    "categoryId": 138
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/jewellery.jpg",
    "categoryName": "jewellery",
    "categoryId": 41
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/clocks.jpg",
    "categoryName": "clocks",
    "categoryId": 137
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/crystalgifts.jpg",
    "categoryName": "crystal gifts",
    "categoryId": 136
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/lamps.jpg",
    "categoryName": "lamps",
    "categoryId": 97
}, {
    "categoryImage": "https://www.winni.in/assets/img/app/city-home/slambook.jpg",
    "categoryName": "slambook",
    "categoryId": 139
}]
```

I want to get categoryId in console.

I used:

> console.log("categoryId  "+cityProduct[0].categoryId);

But some error came, I will show you screen shot of console error:
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: `$scope.cityProduct !=  cityProduct`

Comment: ISTR that `.success` is deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line confused you:

```
$scope.cityProduct = data;
```

The data received in succession is an array of objects as a JSON response. Array elements are accessed with indices i.e. `$scope.cityProduct[0]`.

```
console.log("aaaaaaa" + cityProduct.categoryId);
```

In that line, you were supposed to write `$scope.` before `cityProduct.categoryId`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
.controller('MyControllerCity',function($scope, $http){ 
        $http({
                method:'get',
                url:'http://192.168.0.3/sf/app/city-home/1',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            }).success(function(data, status,headers, config) {
                $scope.cityProduct = data;
                // to access first element's categoryId 
                console.log("aaaaaaa" + $scope.cityProduct[0].categoryId);
                // iterate here to access all elements' categoryId
                $scope.cityProduct.forEach(function(product) {
                 console.log(product.categoryId);
                }); 
            }).error(function(data, status, headers ,config) {

        })

})
```

Comment: Your answer approximately correct. But i want only one id at time. Because i want to show data according to category. Like person click on flowers then only flowers category show.

Comment: I want to this category Id append on other url.

Comment: Just I updated my question. Please check. If  click on cakes category then cake id will come. if click on flowers category then flowers id will come.

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer approx correcting and voting up :) Yes you can use category_id in html ng-repeat and use in url to open

Comment: change <a href="#/category-prduct" to <a href="#/{{prdct_categoryId}}" it will use Id of flowers and cakes on respective clicks and if your app has that page on url it will take you there

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is an array of objects, so you need to access it like so:

```
$scope.cityProduct[0].categoryId
```

Or something more dynamic:

```
$scope.cityProduct.forEach(function(product) {
    console.log(product.categoryId);
});
```

Also notice that you missed out $scope after setting the cityProduct variable for the first time.

Comment: Yep, just noticed that myself! Mornings are hard :( fixed it!

Comment: @millerbr. I used console.log(cityProduct[0].categoryId) But it show some error.

Comment: @varunsharma I think I have covered the answer for the mistake you are making-- look at my answer. Let me know if you still face problem.

Comment: @millerbr. please check my updated question. I want to show only current click category ID.If click on cakes category then cake id will come. if click on flowers category then flowers id will come.

Comment: You have saved your data in $scope.cityProduct but are trying to access without the $scope part - have a look at my answer, and you can see that in the for loop line, I have included the $scope. part